# Using a variable to switch between input arrays

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the value from a drop down list to reference an array which I am using to load some data via an API in the backend.  So the drop down would return the variable name but then I need to send the associated array to the function.  I tried (...selected_basket) syntax but that send the name not the array to the function.

```
    var REITS = ['DIR-UN.TO', 'HR-UN.TO'];
    var Airlines = ['AC.TO', 'IAG.LSE', 'RYA.LSE', 'AAL', 'UAL'];
    var Insurance = ['CB.US', 'AIG.US', 'CS.PA', 'ALV.XETRA', 'PNGAY.US'];
    var Technology = ['MSFT', 'AMZN', 'NOW', 'CRM'];

    export function dropdown1_change(event) {
        selected_basket = $w("#dropdown1").value;
        load_table(selected_basket);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a lookup object to contain those arrays:

```
var REITS = ['DIR-UN.TO', 'HR-UN.TO'];
var Airlines = ['AC.TO', 'IAG.LSE', 'RYA.LSE', 'AAL', 'UAL'];
var Insurance = ['CB.US', 'AIG.US', 'CS.PA', 'ALV.XETRA', 'PNGAY.US'];
var Technology = ['MSFT', 'AMZN', 'NOW', 'CRM'];
var Lookup = {REITS, Airlines, Insurance, Technology};

export function dropdown1_change(event) {
    selected_basket = Lookup[$w("#dropdown1").value];
    load_table(selected_basket);
}
```

Comment: Of course, you should probably define the data as `data = { airlines: [...], ... }` in the first place.

Comment: @deceze Yeah, and use `const` instead of `var`, and respect naming conventions for variables and method names, ... I thought it better to not muddy the waters.